# Unable to connect to Google One VPN

Tags: google, android-11, vpn

When I first set up Google One, I was able to connect to their VPN with my android tablet but it stopped working shortly after and hasn't been able to reconnect since. The following messages just keep cycling:

- "VPN is connecting..."
- "VPN has disconnected. Trying to reconnect VPN..."

I have tried:

- restarting
- disconnecting from the VPN on my other devices before attempting to connect with the tablet
- reinstalling Google One
- clearing the Google One app cache

The VPN works fine on my android phone.

It seems to be impossible to obtain any useful help from Google. Would appreciate any advice on how to resolve this.

Device type: Samsung Galaxy Tab A

Android version: 11 - no further updates currently available

Comment: FYI: There is a limit of 6 devices per family group: https://blog.google/products/google-one/common-questions-vpn-google-one/

Comment: Thanks for sharing that.  I'm only trying to use 2 devices at the moment.